# Chrome is not running javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am learning javascript and I made a webpage with news API. the problem is that when I open my index.html file with the live server in vs code is working fine but when I go to my folder and open the HTML file the javascript is not working.
[image: image of index.html in live server]

this is index.html in live server vs code working perfectly

[image: image of index.html when I open it from the folder]

this is image of same file when I open it from my folder

I am new to web development, not even new I am still a student.
is it not supposed to work or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: You probably didnt import the.js file properly. Open the Dev-Tools, open the network tab and reload the page. Than post a screenshot of that in here.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: Maybe you've used script files of type "module". Without any code it''s just guessing though.

Answer (score 0):

you need the development server to serve the statics files, such as images to browser.
browser will request static files from the server, and loaded in browser.
that is why without vscode liveserver, you do not see images.

Answer (score 0):

You are required to serve the files. use a tool like [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/windows/) for that.

After startup you have to change the Webserver to the folder containing your index.html ([Documentation](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Windows/Preferences/Web-Server/index.html))

If you are using a more complex framework additional steps can be required.